# How to change one xml to another

Tags: .net, xml

I am new in XML parsing. I have a Xml File and i need to extract some element from this xml and create a new xml file with these selected element and some extra element.

what do i need to understand before start this and how to do it.?

Comment: Consider using XSLT, it was created for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to XML makes this very easy. For example, this will copy all the `foo` elements from `existing.xml` into `new.xml` under an `imported` element, creating an `other` element at the same time:

```
XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load("existing.xml");
var elementsToCopy = oldDoc.Descendants("foo");

var newDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("imported", elementsToCopy),
        new XElement("other")
    )
);
newDoc.Save("new.xml");
```

While XSLT (suggested elsewhere) would quite possibly work very well, I've always found it somewhat fiddly to use - and I'd prefer not to have to learn another language for something I can achieve easily within C#. YMMV.

Comment: XDocument (like XmlDocument) presumably loads the whole document into memory.  So this recommendation may not be appropriate for very large XML files.

Comment: @Joe: While this is true, the size of memory on most modern machines means you can load some pretty huge XML files without worrying - to the extent that unless someone *says* the XML file is enormous, it's likely not to be a problem.

Comment: True, especially in 64-bit apps, but I think this difference betweek XmlDocument/XDocument and XmlReader is something the OP needs to be aware of, since he asked "... what do i need to understand before start this "

Answer (score 5):

> what do i need to understand before start this and how to do it.?

You may take a look at the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class which allows you to manipulate XML files. Another possibility is to read about [XSL transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).

Answer (score 1):

I would stronly recommend you to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Here is good tutorial on this topic:

[Using LINQ to XML to Add Data to XML File in C#](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/xml/linq-to-xml-adding-cs.aspx)